# Must the electromagnetic 2-form be harmonic in vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, vacuum, boundary-conditions, topology

The Maxwell equations in vacuum are $dF=0$ and $d*F=0$. Is this not the same as saying $F$ is both closed and co-closed, and hence harmonic? But Hodge's theorem says the space of harmonic $p$-forms on a manifold is isomorphic to its $p$th cohomology, which seems to imply that the only solution to Maxwell's equations in vacuum on $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $F=0$? Presumably I have missed something here?

Comment: Maybe it would be good to add what $F$, coclosure and Hodge's theorem are.

Answer (score 0):

You've just forgotten the space has to be compact.

Think about the simple case $p = 0$. This is the set of harmonic functions $\nabla^2 f = 0$. Indeed, on a compact connected space the zeroth cohomology group vanishes, and there are no nontrivial solutions for $f$. But on $\mathbb{R}^n$ there are plenty of solutions, one example being $e^z$ on the plane.

If you require $F$ to vanish at infinity, we may compactify $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $S^n$, and the theorem does apply.

Comment: With this caveat this seems like a really nice result - is there anything I can do with the knowledge that there are exactly $b^2$ independent solutions on a compact manifold/that vanish at infinity?